# How to run a task in the background until user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm from a .NET background, but I notice that `asyncio` behaves differently to `async` and `await` in .NET:

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Start a task (`a`) that does some compute
2. Start a task (`b`) that waits for user input to quit
3. await task `b` (user has quitted)
4. cancel task `a`

The following does not execute task `a` at all:

```
processing = asyncio.create_task(do_processing())

user_finished = asyncio.create_task(stdin_listener())

await user_finished

processing.cancel()
```

The reason I understand is because `processing` is never awaited, however if I await this task, it will never return because it will never reach the `cancel()`.

I've had a look through the docs, and can't find this simple example, or been able to piece this together. Just not familiar with this API, so please enlighten me.

Edit:
I've discovered that the handling of tasks above is correct. However, in the method `stdin_listener()`, I have a call to:

```
input("Press Q to quit\n")
```

which is blocking. I'm going to look into other approaches to this call.

Comment: Without seeing `do_processing` and `stdin_listener` it’s hard to provide meaningful help, but my guess is that the latter doesn’t await anything that yields back to the event loop so the former never gets a chance to start.

Comment: Ok, great.  Yep, that makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I've decided to use SIGINT to close out:

```
exiting = False


        async def do_processing():
            global exiting
            while not exiting:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                # do processing here


        def handler(signal_received, frame):
            global exiting
            # Handle any cleanup here
            print('SIGINT or CTRL-C detected. Exiting gracefully')
            exiting = True

        signal(SIGINT, handler)

        await asyncio.create_task(do_processing())

        # post processing
```

Link to further explanation:
https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-catch-sigint-ctrl-c

Comment: Please read about [answer]. While the contents of this link might actually solve the problem, link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Links tend to break and then the answer loses its value. It is better to include the essential parts of the link as text in the answer itself and provide the link as a reference. Your plain-text answer looks like: `I've decided to use SIGINT to close out, based on this pattern: <line>` which doesn't provide much information. If you think the link alone can help, post it as a comment (if you have 50 rep) instead.